# Using VSCode tabnine as a secondary code completion

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, tabnine

[Tabnine](https://www.tabnine.com/) is a great tool, however on a day to day basis I prefer to use the results generated by VSCode intellisense as a first choice and the tabnine results as a second choice.

I have not been able to find a valid configuration to set tabnine as second choice of results, any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: No sir, I have disabled this extension for the moment

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Code AutoComplete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=svipas.code-autocomplete) which internally use tabnine and do these priority stuffs.

Comment: It's still putting TabNine's text suggestion beore Intellisense's variable, for instance. how can this be changed?

Comment: might not be changed. and not always putting tabnines suggestion before.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean your claim is not always true. but sometime happens